# Getting a handle on basic Redux with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to both React as a framework and React Native development
I have learnt that the best way to manage things like in-app notifications, etc is to use Redux to act as a state manager (of sorts, I would prefer to have the redux used outside of my react navigation scope)

I have watched tutorials on redux by itself (egghead.io) and it made sense;

But every tutorial I find on implementing it within React Native seems so overly complex.

I only wish to pass data; like network request results, current settings from Async Storage (instead of loading it on each different module like I am currently)

I understand that I dispatch a command of sorts; the reducer interprets this and outputs a new state; but I dont understand how I ca n actually use this in practical terms.

My current App.js with attempting to impliment redux but I have no idea how child stacks/screens/etc can access and dispatch new commands from this:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator,createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SearchTab from './components/Tabs/SearchTab';
import HomeTab from './components/Tabs/HomeTab';
import ScannerTab from './components/Tabs/ScannerTab';
import SettingsTab from './components/Tabs/SettingsTab';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import StockModal from './components/Modals/StockModal';
import NotificationModal from './components/Modals/NotificationModal';

//redux
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import navigation from './redux/reducers/reducer'

const reducer = combineReducers({ navigation });
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(logger));

class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RootStack

                />
            </Provider>
        );
    };
}

//Connect everything
export default Root;

const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeTab,
        Search: SearchTab,
        Scanner: ScannerTab,
        Settings: SettingsTab,
        //Todo: Total overlay modals HERE
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;

                if (routeName === 'Home') {
                    iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
                    iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }else if (routeName === 'Scanner') {
                    iconName = `ios-barcode${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }else if (routeName === 'Search') {
                    iconName = `ios-search${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }
                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        },
    }
);

RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: MainStack,
        },
        QuickStockModal: {
            screen: StockModal,
        },
        NotificationModal: {
            screen: NotificationModal,
        }
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none',
        cardStyle:{
            backgroundColor:"transparent",
            opacity:0.99
        }
    }
);
```

And my reducer is a very simple implimentation;

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'GET_SERVER':
            return {
                ...state,
                server: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Just meant to return the state; or pass basic data

But I dont understand when I can actually access the ability to dispatch.

I am failing to connect the dots; I understand this isnt the most appropriate question for SO but I cant think of what else to do and im stuck in a slump development wise and I need to get out of it to remain productive ):

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://learn.handlebarlabs.com/p/react-native-basics-build-a-currency-converter

Comment: using redux with React.Components does not differ between react-native and react. If a tutorial shows you how to use it with react then that should be transferable to react-native. In your code example above I do not see where you are using `connect`, are you using `connect`? calling `connect` on a component passes a prop called `dispatch` to your components. `dispatch` is a function which accepts action-creators as arguments. `this.props.dispatch(actionCreator(payload))` is how to update your store.

Comment: Ah I see! That’s very helpful thanks I’m going to try and set that up and test it appreciate it